# MVC3 Routing: passing a portion of the route as a "path" parameter

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

Let's say I have an action like

```
public ActionResult TheAction(string path) { ... }
```

What I want to do is to have a request like www.myapp.com/controller/TheAction/path/to/content pass the "path/to/content" part of the route as the "path" parameter to the action.

My guess is that I'd have to fiddle with a custom route/request handler but before donning the complicator's gloves I wanted to see if you guys had any other suggestions.

Comment: +1 for the "Complicator's gloves" statement - thats awesome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just register `/{controller}/{action}/{*path}` in your route registration.

That makes the last parameter a catch-all, so it will include the rest of the path, just like you want.

So it will look something like:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "HasCatchAllPath", 
            "{controller}/{action}/{*path}", 
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }  
        );
```

Comment: Thanks a heap, just what I needed.